# Does scaling property fail for the Fourier transform of $e^{-|t|}$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $x(t) = e^{-|t|}$ and $X(\omega) = \mathcal F\{\mathrm e^{-|t|}\}$ be the Fourier Transform of $x(t)$, which is given by
$$X(\omega) = \frac {2} {1+\omega^2}\tag{1}$$
Then, the scaling property states that:
$$\mathcal F \{x(at)\} = \frac {1} {|a|} X\left(\frac {\omega} {a}\right)\tag{2}$$
Now, let me have $a = j$, where $j = \sqrt{-1}$.
$$\mathcal F \{x(jt)\} = \frac {1} {|j|} X\left(\frac {\omega} {j}\right) = 1 \frac {2} {1+\left(\frac {\omega} {j}\right)^2} = \frac {2} {1-\omega^2}\tag{3}$$
But, if we wouldn't use the scaling property, we would find following result:
$$\mathcal F \{x(jt)\} = \mathcal F \{e^{-|jt|}\} = \mathcal F \{e^{-|t|}\} = \frac {2} {1+\omega^2}\tag{4}$$

Obviously, $\frac {2} {1-\omega^2} \neq \frac {2} {1+\omega^2}$.

The fact that $x(jt)=x(t)$ seems to cause the problem.

Am I doing a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Scaling is only reliable for _real_ scaling, not other complex numbers. Sure, in some cases, for subtler reasons, a non-real scaling makes sense, and gives the expected outcome, but not in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$t$ of the Fourier transform is only defined over the real numbers. Multiplying $t$ by $j$ breaks this.

Comment: Even if when it is justified by analytic continuation, it happens we do such complex change of variables, for example to compute $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2/2} e^{-st}dt = e^{s^2/2} \sqrt{\pi}$ for $ s \in \mathbb{C}$